# Complex Query in MS Access With Memory

Tags: memory

For work I have a table that keeps track of all assignments individuals are given and which shift they are given.  I have this linked to a Sharepoint server, so I am using MSAccess 2010 to query data and get reports.  I am trying to make a query that will give me the number of days an engineer has been on a particular shift in order to prioritize rotations.  Easy right?  Well, there will be multiple assignments per shift.  Here is an example of the issue:

```
Name    Assignment Shift        Date of Assignment
John    A          Day          1/1/2012
John    B          Day          4/10/2012
Sarah   C          Night        2/2/2012
Sarah   D          Night        3/2/2012
Bill    E          Day          2/20/2012
Sally   F          Night        2/25/2012
```

So far by using multiple queries I have been able to get the number of days on the LAST assignment (per shift) but this will not account for someone who has been given different assignments on the same shift.  Using the above table and with the method (MAX of the last assignment per shift) I would rotate **Bill** with **Sally** because **Bill** would appear to be the day shift for the longest, and **Sally** has been on the night shift for the longest.  In actuality **John** should be rotated with **Sarah**.

Answer (score 0):

You wan to go with a SUM() of the computed time while doing a GROUP BY Name,Shift,Date.  You dont want to have the assignment in your grouping.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  The table above is a simple example, the real table will have John on Night assignments in between.  With the number of entries I dont know how I would sum up the time from the last known Day (or night) assignment with the previous Day (or night) assignment until there is a change in the assignment to Night.